# The order of destructor

Tags: c++, class, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Ghost{
public:
    Ghost(){
        strcpy(name, "");
        cout << "Ghost(" << name <<")" <<endl;
    }

    Ghost(char n[]){
        strcpy(name, n);
        cout << "Ghost(" << name << ")" << endl;
    }
    ~Ghost(){
        cout <<"~Ghost(" << name << ")" << endl;
    }

private:
    char name[20];
};

class PacMan{
public:
    PacMan(){
        inky = new Ghost("Inky");
        pinky = NULL;
        cout << "PacMan()" << endl;
    }

    PacMan(Ghost* other){
        inky = NULL;
        pinky = other;
        cout << "PacMan(other)" << endl;
    }

    ~PacMan(){
        if (inky!= NULL)
            delete inky;
        cout <<"~PacMan()" << endl;
    }

private:
    Ghost blinky;
    Ghost *inky;
    Ghost *pinky;
};

int main(){
    PacMan pm1;
    Ghost* other = new Ghost("other");
    PacMan* pm2 = new PacMan(other);

    delete pm2;
    delete other;

    return 0;
}
```

For this program, it output:

```
Ghost()
Ghost(Inky)
PacMan()
Ghost(other)
Ghost()
PacMan(other)
~PacMan()
~Ghost()
~Ghost(other)
~Ghost(Inky)
~PacMan()
~Ghost()
```

I wanted to know where the first output *Ghost()* come from, and why the last three output wasn't

```
~PacMan()
~Ghost(Inky)
~Ghost()
```

I think the order of destructor is the opposite of the constructor order, is it true?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `delete nullptr;` is legal. `if ( p != nullptr ) delete p;` is an anti pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Ghost is the `PacMan` member `blinky`.

About the last order: Destroying `pm1` exectutes

```
~PacMan(){
        if (inky!= NULL)
            delete inky;
        cout <<"~PacMan()" << endl;
    }
```

and then `blinky` is deleted too.
If you want the opposite order, you've to write it here.